# How to filter specific row in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a table that have a column "time" store the date stamp every five minutes , 
just like this :

```
time
20120701 00:00:00
20120701 00:05:00
20120701 00:10:00
20120701 00:15:00
....
```

but interval between the rows sometimes are longer than 5 minites, like

```
20120703 00:00:00
20120703 00:15:00
```

What I want to do is to find out all these time stamps that the interval between them is longer than 5 minutes.

Is that possible to find out the result with just one sql sentence.

Thanks for kind help!

Comment: I doubt that this is doable in SQL in any sane manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select time from table where time not in
(
select t1.time from table as t1 inner join table as t2 on t1.time=t2.time-interval 5 minute
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rank to compare the previous row with the 'current' one and check if it's greater than 5 minutes.
Have a look here to see how to create a rank:
[Rank function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function)